# Parsererror for jQuery corss domain ajax request to Spring Rest web service

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, cross-domain, restful-url

i have deployed a REST web service and the service return String as a response.
When i send cross domain jQuery ajax request i get 'parsererror'.

Below is Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/TestService",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String testServiceGet()
{
     return "This is GET";
}
```

Below is jQuery ajax() method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Example_REST_WS_Deploy/service/TestService',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    success : function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
       alert(data);
    },
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert("Error ->" + textStatus);
    }
});
```

The error which we received in FF browser error console is as below:

```
SyntexError: missing ; before statement
This is GET
-----^
```

Please help as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it solved.

I remove the `contentType: 'text/plain'`, from the ajax method and it's working fine.